# Олимпиадная задача по C++: поиск простого числа в матрице с особым условием

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада, простые-числа

**Условие:**

Вам дана таблица NxM, в каждой ячейке которой написана какая-то цифра. Будем считать, что число есть в этой таблице, если его можно “прочитать” в каком-то месте этой таблицы по горизонтали, по вертикали или по диагонали (вправо, вниз, или вправо-вниз).
Найдите количество и сумму всех простых чисел, состоящих не более чем из 6 цифр, которые есть в этой таблице. Если какое-то число повторяется несколько раз в разных местах таблицы, то нужно учитывать все эти вхождения. Числа не должны начинаться с нуля.

**Входные и выходные данные:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Мое решение:**

Сначала я подумал, что задача из простых, простым перебором проверять числа в матрице, для чего я написал такую функцию проверки :

```
bool is_prime(int n) 
{
    if(n == 2) return true;
    if(n == 1 || n%2==0) return false;
    int d = 3; // делитель
    while(d*d <= n)
    {
        if(n%d == 0) return false;      
        d+=2;
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Когда в результате я увидел, что количество найденных простых чисел не совпадает с B.out, то понял, что число так же можно образовать при помощи 2 соседних цифр (по диагонали, вертикали и горизонтали.)

Прим. число - 17. Цифра 1 + по диагонали цифра 7 образует простое число 17.
Нет идей как можно обновить мой код, чтобы он проверял так же и эти собранные числа из соседних цифр. NEED HELP

Comment: Это случайная олимпиадная задача или в рамках изучения какой-либо темы?

Comment: Городская олимпиада 2014 год (Астана, Казахстан), Для 9-11 классов.. Каких то определенных тем нет, т.е. да, случайная.

Comment: Мне кажется, что полный перебор тут будет плохо работать. Скорее всего, должна быть многомерная динамика -  что-нибудь из серии count[6][N][M], где count[k][i][j] - количество простых чисел длиной не более k в прямоугольнике со сторонами i и j. Над самой формулой уже нужно подумать, возможно, есть какой-то быстрый способ проверять простоту чисел со смещением.

Comment: Аналогично, для суммы простых чисел.

Comment: Если и перебором - то надо один раз соорудить таблицу простых чисел до 1000000... Но простой перебор - это проверка до 40 миллионов чисел. Ограничения там есть? на память, время?

Answer (score 3):

В принципе работает быстро даже перебором... У меня 1500x1500 считало - 0.5с - таблицу, и еще меньше секунды - все варианты.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

bitset<1000000> primes;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // make table
    primes[2] = true;
    for(int i = 3; i < 1000000; i += 2)
    {
        bool is_prime = true;
        for(int j = 3; j*j <= i; ++j)
        {
            if (!primes[j]) continue;
            if (i%j == 0)
            {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_prime) primes[i] = true;
    }

    int N, M;
    cin >> N >> M;
    unsigned char ** data = new unsigned char*[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) data[i] = new unsigned char[M];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            cin >> data[i][j];
            data[i][j] -= '0';
        }
    }

    int count = 0;
    long long sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            if (data[i][j] == 0) continue;
            if (primes[data[i][j]])
            {
                ++count;
                sum += data[i][j];
            }
            // right
            int val = data[i][j];
            for(int k = 1; k < 6; ++k)
            {
                if (j+k >= M) break;
                val = val*10 + data[i][j+k];
                if (primes[val])
                {
                    ++count; sum += val;
                }
            }
            // down
            val = data[i][j];
            for(int k = 1; k < 6; ++k)
            {
                if (i+k >= N) break;
                val = val*10 + data[i+k][j];
                if (primes[val])
                {
                    ++count; sum += val;
                }
            }
            // diag
            val = data[i][j];
            for(int k = 1; k < 6; ++k)
            {
                if (i+k >= N || j+k >= M) break;
                val = val*10 + data[i+k][j+k];
                if (primes[val])
                {
                    ++count; sum += val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << count << " " << sum << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае имеет смысл проверять на простоту другим способом.

Для начала запустим решето эратосфена для чисел длины до шести, то есть размера k < 1e6. Оно отработает за O(kloglogk), то есть что-то вроде O(1e7), данные рассуждения здесь даны для понимания того, что это уложится в лимит по времени. Можем также использовать линейное решето эратосфена, чтобы добиться в данном случае времени O(k), однако это нам не потребуется.

После этого за O(nm) мы переберем каждую клетку поля и будем пытаться строить число во все стороны, а проверка будет происходить за O(1), будем просто проверять помечено ли данное число как простое или нет.

Тогда суммарное время работы O(nm + 1e7), что вполне уложится в наши ограничения, учитывая что nm <= ~3e6.

Ваш алгоритм не работает, поскольку вы каждый раз проверяете простоту за корень, то есть время вашего алгоритма порядка O(1000nm), что слишком много.